# Error: Syntax in assignment statement l-value

Tags: verilog

This is the Verilog code.

```
module Problem1(x,y,z,F1,F2,F3);
input  [1:0] x,y;
input wire z;

output F1, F2; 
reg F1 , F2; 

output wire [1:0] F3;

assign F3 = x&y;

always @* begin 
    if(z)
        assign F1 = x[0];
    else
        assign F1 = x[1];
    sub(z,F2);
end
endmodule

module sub(F,x);
task sub;
    output reg F;
    input x;
    always @* begin
        case(x)
        0:F = 1;
        1:F = 0;
        endcase
    end
endtask
endmodule
```

I'm getting the following errors.  Can you help me understand how to fix them?

```
$iverilog -o main *.v
main.v:25: syntax error
main.v:27: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.
main.v:28: syntax error
main.v:28: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.
main.v:29: syntax error
I give up.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors with your code.

Do not use the `assign` keyword to make an assignment to a `reg` (`F1`).

Do not place a module instance (`sub`) inside an `always` block.

Use an instance name for your `sub` module instance.

Do not create a `task` with the same name as a module (`sub`).  There is no need for the `task/endtask` in this case.

Here is a version which compiles cleanly for me:

```
module Problem1(x,y,z,F1,F2,F3);
input  [1:0] x,y;
input wire z;

output F1, F2; 
reg F1 , F2; 

output wire [1:0] F3;

assign F3 = x&y;

always @* begin 
    if(z)
        F1 = x[0];
    else
        F1 = x[1];
end

sub sub (z,F2);

endmodule

module sub(F,x);
    output reg F;
    input x;
    always @* begin
        case(x)
        0:F = 1;
        1:F = 0;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```